# Windows Form multiple designer for a control

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I made a custom designer for a control. The problem is that the base class has a designer, too. Since it's marked as internal, I can't inherit from it. Is there a way to force the designer to use multiple designers for a control?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerattribute?view=net-6.0](Designer Attribute). Windows Form controls can be marked with the 'Designer' attribute. The class you specify inside the attribute manages a control's design-time behavior. Both the original control and my custom one have the Designer attribute set. The problem is that the designer only uses the first one it encounters. The original control has its designer class marked as internal, so I can't simply inherit it. Is it possible to force the designer to initiate multiple designers for a control?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/150801/Inheriting-from-an-Internal-WinForms-Designer. I found a nice blog about my specific problem.